# ASP.NET MVC Core application does not instantiate HomeController to handle default route

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, autofac

I'm using Autofac as my dependency resolver for an ASP.NET Core 1.1 application. I'm not using a startup class, rather I'm using a base class that configures everything including the Autofac container, and then allows a derived class to override methods for custom configuration.

Here's the basic setup of the host in the base class' initialization method:

```
_server = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseUrls(Settings.AspNet.Urls)
    .UseKestrel()
    .UseIISIntegration()
    .UseContentRoot(_directory)
    .ConfigureServices(services => ConfigureServicesInternal(services, containerBuilder))
    .Configure(app => ConfigureInternal(app, containerBuilder))
    .Build();
 _server.Run();
```

### `ConfigureServices()`

As you can see there is not Startup class involved. Here's what the base class' 
 `ConfigureServicesInternal` method does:

```
services.AddAutofac();
services.AddSingleton(Settings);

// Allow derived class to add services
ConfigureServices(services);

// Copy everything over to the Autofac container builder
builder.Populate(services);

// Allow derived class to register dependencies in the Autofac container
ConfigureContainer(builder);
```

Here's the derived class' `ConfigureServices` method:

```
// Tried with and without AddControllersAsServices(), no difference
services.AddMvcCore().AddControllersAsServices();
```

The derived class' `ConfigureContainer` method is empty.

### `Configure()`

Here's the base class `Configure` method:

```
// Allow derived class to configure the app
Configure(app);

// Storing a reference to the Autofac container in the base class because I need it later
Container = builder.Build();

// Let Autofac take over. I tried removing this, and it did not help
app.ApplicationServices = new AutofacServiceProvider(Container);
```

And here's the derived class' `Configure` method:

```
// Also tried UseMvc(route => route.MapRoute(...)), no difference
app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
```

Browing to the root of the application I get a 404. I can add Routing as a service as well as static files, and they both work (e.g. I can get a 200 response from this application, just not from an MVC controller).

I've tried inheriting from `Controller` but that also does not make a difference. I tried removing all constructor injection from the HomeController, still no luck.

Tried running it using IIS Express, no result.

Tried browing directly to the route, e.g. http://localhost:8001/home/index/, but again no luck.

There's no logging other than:

> [20:58:26 INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:8001/
>
> [20:58:26 INF] Request finished in 304.8803ms 404

How can I debug this issue?

---

Edit:

The problem is in passing `ConfigureInternal` as the `Configure` method and calling a derived class' `Configure` method from within `ConfigureInternal`. When I do that, it starts returning a 404 for the default route.

When I pass the derived class' `Configure` method, I can see resolved services being added to the application after each `app.UseSomething()` call.

I can step through both methods, and I can see extra services being added after each use call in the derived class' `Configure` method (e.g. `app.UseRouter()` adds routing options and a 'routing marker service', and `app.UseMvcWithDefaultRouter()` adds another 19 services).

This happens just as well when I pass the base class' `ConfigureInternal` method, and call the base class' `Configure` method. So I don't understand why it makes a difference though...

Comment: I would say follow the documentation (http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html). FWIW, all their examples there actually *do* utilize the `Startup` class, but that may not have anything to do with anything. There is a section talking about controllers, that might be of interest to you though. Regardless, make sure you're doing everything in the example code, and I'd assume you'd be golden.

Comment: Your code works fine for me both in console and in iis express, so maybe you should narrow down to minimal complete example (and publish it somewhere for download\clone), or provide more info  (not sure which though).